# Make query parameter with vue router reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to build a search page with Vue and I want the query text that the user enters in an input field to be reactive with the query parameter in the URL
eg:

input: foo
url:   http://localhost:8080/search?query=foo

and if the user continues to type `bar` in the input field, I want to get the URL to updated to http://localhost:8080/search?query=foobar without the navigating via the router.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make `$route.query` the [source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth), then when you want to mutate its value you just need to do a `$router.replace()` operation with the updated query value.

Off the cuff:

```vue
<input :value="$route.query.q" @input="onInput">
```

```es6
onInput(e) {
  this.$router.replace({
    query: {
      ...this.$route.query,
      q: e.target.value,
    }
  })
}
```

The `...this.$route.query` is to preserve any other query parameters that may exist; if you only have `q` then it isn't necessary (also you may need to use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead since support for [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is patchy right now).